# Max function not working on date field

Tags: mysql

I am trying to apply max function on date field but i am unable to get required result.Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    IC.InsuredId, 
    IC.CntcInfoTxt,
    IC.CntcTypeCd,
    MAX(IC.ExpDt)ExpiryDate
From InsuredContact  IC
Where CntcTypeCd = 'EML' and ExpDt < getdate() and InsuredId = 10
Group by IC.InsuredId,IC.CntcInfoTxt,IC.CntcTypeCd
```

Can you please point out what mistake i am doing 
My date field contain data like this `2006-12-31 00:00:00.000` ,`2005-12-31 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Is it that you typed mac instead of max?

Comment: Is your date field a DATETIME or CHAR?

Comment: @barmar: normally would be relevant, but OP's dates appear to be "most significant value first", with proper padding, so they'd naturally sort properly anyways.

Comment: I am doing max typing error

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `getdate()` function.

Comment: The function for the current date and time is `NOW()`.

Comment: field type is Datetime

Comment: What result *are* you getting?

Comment: I am getting 2005-12-31 00:00:00.000 first then 2006-12-31 00:00:00.000. I have tried both MAX and MIN function

Comment: Load sqlfiddle.com with sample data duplicating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
MAX(TO_DAYS(IC.ExpDt))ExpiryDate
```

The function TO_DAYS() will return the number of days from the date `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000` to `IC.ExpDt`.

And change the `getdate()` function (which I think doesn't exist on MySQL !) to `NOW()`.